# Trigger build in OpenShift on change in Gitlab container registry

Tags: gitlab, openshift, gitlab-ci

I am having a trouble to figure out how OpenShift can trigger deployment based on change in GitLab container registry. I have configured option in OpenShift called `Deploy an existing Image from an Image Stream or Image registry.` This works and I can see my pod up and running. When I tried updating docker image and pushed to GitLab container registry, I did not see any new deployment in OpenShift. Please guide.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenShift can automatically trigger redeployment on an image update, but only if the image changes in an `ImageStreamTag` resource on the same cluster.

The `image.openshift.io/triggers` annotation [can be configured](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.10/openshift_images/triggering-updates-on-imagestream-changes.html#images-triggering-updates-imagestream-changes-kubernetes-about_triggering-updates-on-imagestream-changes) in the deployment to reference an `ImageStreamTag` on the local cluster.

In the following example, the Deployment will be triggered by an update of the `-n ci imagestreamtag mirror:latest` tag.

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    image.openshift.io/triggers: '[{"from":{"kind":"ImageStreamTag","name":"content-mirror:latest","namespace":"ci"},"fieldPath":"spec.template.spec.containers[?(@.name==\"mirror\")].image"}]'
  name: base-4-10
  namespace: app
spec:
...
```

To achieve the same thing, you can either:

#### Push directly to the cluster registry

Establish an `ImageStream` resource in your cluster and push your image there
instead of the GitLab container registry. Configure your Deployment to be reactive to changes to the tag you push the image to.

#### Periodically import the image from GitLab into an ImageStream

ImageStreams can be [configured to periodically import](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.10/openshift_images/image-streams-manage.html#images-imagestream-import_image-streams-managing) external images. The import happens every 15 minutes.

1. Create a new `ImageStream` like `app-images`.
2. Tag your GitLab image into the `ImageStream` like: `oc tag docker.io/app:latest app-images:app --scheduled`
3. Configure your Deployment's `image.openshift.io/triggers` annotation to be reactive to the `app-images:myapp` `ImageStreamTag`.